# What does 之为 mean in 如果把人生比之为杠杆...?

Tags: grammar, meaning

What does 之为 mean in the following sentence?

如果把人生比之为杠杆，信念则好像是它的“支点”，具备这个恰当的支点，才可能成为一个强有力的人。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [人生][比之为][杠杆]

- [人生] (life) is the main object.
- [比] short for [比喻] (metaphorize). It is the verb.
- [之] (it) functions as an objective pronoun. In this case, the object is '人生'
- [为] (as being) is the auxiliary verb.
- [杠杆] (lever) is the relative object, which is the 'metaphor' for ' '人生'

'**之为**' means '**it as being**' here.

"把人生**比之**为杠杆" = "Take life and metaphorize **it as being** a lever."

*Depend on the object, '之' can represent any objective pronoun (that, him, her them, it)

More Example:

"把日本視**之为**敵人" = "Take Japan and see **it as being** an enemy"

> *You can omit  the objective pronoun '之' in these sentence:
>
> '把人生比为杠杆' ;  '把日本視为敵人'

~

> *You can omit 'being' in these sentence:
>
> 'metaphorize life as a 'lever' ; 'see Japan as an enemy'

Answer (score 2):

？？？This question is on more promoted to the top, but I do not agree with the existing answers.

This is a typical syntax error...

如果把人生比作杠杆

人生 is the object, 比 is the predicate. 把 reverses their order.

If we add 之, we have a redundant object. So it is incorrect.

In fact the whole sentence is grammarly incorrect, written by some low-educated person...

The metaphor is unresonable, the subject is missed and the syntax is erroneous.

如果把人生比**作**杠杆，信念则**是**（人生已经是比喻了，信念还“好像”，这并不是在说理时应该有的）它的支点。强烈的信念形成坚实的支点（杠杆一定有支点，不是支点存不存在，而是坚不坚强的问题），人（主语补足）才能强而有力。

Answer (score 1):

Like Tang Ho says,之为 is not 1 word, you could write '之为 = it as' or just leave out 之。

如果把人生比之为杠杆，信念则好像是它的“支点”，具备这个恰当的支点，才可能成为一个强有力的人。
If we liken life to a lever, faith then is the fulcrum, only with suitable leverage point can you become a powerful person.

(Did my best to alliterate!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe /shuí/ is the more orthodox pronunciation of 谁, due to the fact that 隹 is pronounced /zhuī/ and all of the 成语 that have 谁 as listed as /shuí/ in dictionaries. The pronunciation of /shéi/ probably is a product of colloquialism